# Getting null value when using getStringwidth

Tags: php, tcpdf

Getting 0 value when using getstringwidth,. Can anyone help me what is wrong with my codes? Am I doing it right?

```
$pdf->GetStringWidth($txtLine[$x], $fntStyle, '', $fntSize);
```

Comment: Have you read the [docs](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a8075c1f04b6fbddc957cff786c4b16d9)?

Comment: I found out that my string $txtLine[$x] is null,. it is due to incorrect variable I declare. I solved this already thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass text in `GetStringWidth()` hope it will works

```
$yourSting = "Come from you content";
$pdf->GetStringWidth($yourSting);
```